# Dual boot Android/Ubuntu Touch - from sdcard?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ubuntu-touch, android, phone

I have an Aquaris E5 Ubuntu edition, and also an Android phone. As an experiment, I would like to make both of these dual boot both Ubuntu Touch and Android, and I've already found this:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation
- http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-articles/2015/09/16/ubuntu-android-installation-process-for-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-e5

However, I'd like to have the second respective OS installed on an added microSD card on the phone; so:

- The Ubuntu phone should have Android on sdcard
- The Android phone should have Ubuntu touch on sdcard

I'm afraid, however, I'm not that familiar with partition layouts on Android, or in general, smartphones - I'm just trying to think in terms of partitions as used on a PC.

So my question is: is this kind of dual boot even possible - and if so, what sort of precautions do I need to take, or in other words, what should I be aware of in terms of partitioning before undertaking something like this?